# How can I subscribe to a one-time signal and conditionally initiate a secondary signal without having the original signal fired twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I would like to subscribe to a signal of one web operation and have it conditionally initiate a secondary web operation.

The code I have put together looks a little like this:

```
RACSignal *asyncWebAPI = [self asyncWebAPI];

@weakify(self)
[asyncWebAPI
 subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
  @strongify(self)
  NSArray *foo = tuple.first;
  [self.bar addObjects:foo];
  self.baz = tuple.second;
 }
 error:^(NSError *error) {
 }];

[[[[asyncWebAPI
    map:^id(RACTuple *tuple) {
      NSArray *foo = tuple.first;
      // Return an array of objects where we want anotherAsyncWebAPI to work with as input
      NSMutableArray *qux = [NSMutableArray array];
      for (id element in foo) {
        if (element.someProperty == -1) {
          [qux addObject:element];
        }
      }
      return [NSArray arrayWithArray:qux];
    }]
   filter:^BOOL(NSArray *qux) {
      // We really only want anotherAsyncWebAPI to perform if the array has elements in it
      return (qux.count != 0);
   }]
  flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSArray *qux) {
      @strongify(self)
      return [self anotherAsyncWebAPI:qux];
  }]
 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     // subscribe and deal with anotherAsyncWebAPI
 }];
```

The above, however, causes the asyncWebAPI to become a hot signal twice.

How can I keep the above as two separate pipelines, as opposed to a single fluent pipeline, while achieving the conditional trigger of a second web operation?

Comment: "How can I keep the above as two separate pipelines, as opposed to a single fluent pipeline" – Can you elaborate on this? The answer may depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the code fragment for clarity.

Comment: Another question: is the above code all in the same method / scope? If not, are you asking how to share an active / in-progress web request between separate parts of the code?

Comment: Yes the code is in the same scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases where the code is in the same scope, you could go about this in by using a `RACSubject` to share the signal, or by using a `RACMulticastConnection`.

Using a `RACSubject`, it would look like:

```
RACSubject *webAPISubject = [RACSubject subject];

[webAPISubject subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
    @strongify(self)
    NSArray *foo = tuple.first;
    [self.bar addObjects:foo];
    self.baz = tuple.second;
 }];

[[[[webAPISubject
    map:^id(RACTuple *tuple) { /* ... */ }]
    filter:^BOOL(NSArray *qux) { /* ... */ }]
    flattenMap:^(NSArray *qux) { /* ... */ }]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) { /* ... */ }];

// Open the gates to let the data flow through the above subscriptions
[[self asyncWebAPI] subscribe:webAPISubject];
```

Alternatively, using a `RACMulticastConnection`, the code will looks much the same as above. The primary difference being the beginning and end.

```
RACMulticastConnection *webAPIConnection = [[self asyncWebAPI] publish];
```

then, replace the references to `asyncWebAPI` in your sample with `webAPIConnection.signal`. Finally, at the end, call:

```
// Open the gates to let the data flow through
[webAPIConnection connect];
```

---

Technically, I don't think there's much of a difference (the `RACMulticastConnection` uses `RACSubject`s behind the scenes), which means it's a matter of taste. Personally, I prefer the use of the subject, I see it as more straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation Dave. The RACSubject really helped explain the underlying work of the multicast connection.

Comment: You're welcome. I too found RACSubject vs RACMulticastConnection comparison to be helpful in understanding.